# Need to check all radio boxes on a page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use javascript to check all radio boxes with a certain ID on a page. The radio buttons all have different names, and are grouped by 3, one for approve, one for deny, one for review...

```
<input type=radio name='21' value='approved' id='approved' title='Approve'>
<input type=radio name='21' value='denied' id='denied' title='Deny'>
<input type=radio name='21' value='review' id='review' checked title='Do nothing right now'>
```

...and so on. I've searched on this site and all over the googles, not really finding a solution that works for me. I have another set of radio buttons on top of the page, that I want to use to control the others, so if I click the "approve" radio up top, all the approve radios are selected, deny does all the denied radio boxes on the page etc.

I am using an onclick on the top radio buttonset to fire a javascript function, but I've no idea what to tell the function to do. I assume that jquery would be able to do this nicely, but cannot seem to come up with the code to do so.

Comment: Do you need just those three radio boxes or do you want _ALL_ checkboxes on the page?

Comment: At the top of the page I have the three "controller" radio boxes. If I choose the "approve" radio in the controller set, I would like all approve radios to be checked, same for deny and review.

Comment: Keep in mind that ID's must be unique.  If you have more than one radio button on your page with an id="denied", for example, you are going to have issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a click function on all radio and update the selection based on its value. See below,

```
//   v--- Refined the selector as you want this to happen only when clicking on the 
//        controller radio options.
$('.controller:radio').click(function () {
    $(':radio[value=' + this.value + ']')).prop('checked', true);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/KvdNq/

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you very much for your help, I think I may have even learned something! :P

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is actually create the groups within separate DIVS.  Then you can loop through all the radios within that particular div and dont need to care about what the IDS are for the respective Radio Buttons.

```
<div id="group1">
    <input type="checkbox" value="group1"/> Check all in this group
    <input type = "radio" value="xx" />
    <input type="radio" value="yy" />
</div>
```

Now you can simply create a function that takes the value of the checkbox, then loops through the matching div, checking all the RADIO BUTTONS within it.  Make sense?

Comment: Or like above, you can use jQuery or SIZZLE for better selector ability :)